# PineScript TradingView: Going beyond a year in code (12months +)

Tags: pine-script

I'm struggling to write an indicator that uses more than 12 months to calculate... Any help appreciated please!

This works up to 12M:

```
year = security(tickerid, '12M', open)
```

But when I go beyond 12 months for example 24 months:

```
multiyear = security(tickerid, '24M', open)
```

I get errors:

> "Invalid value of the resolution argument"

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation (`Ctrl+Click` (PC) or `Cmd+click` (MAC) on function).

> The resolution argument allowable values are:
>
> - 1S, 5S, 15S, 30S - for seconds intervals (chart resolution should be less than or equal to the requested resolution)
> - from 1 to 1440 for minutes
> - from 1D to 365D for days
> - from 1W to 52W for weeks
> - from 1M to 12M for months

Going beyond 12+ months seems to be not possible.

Comment: Thank you for this information. It's hard to believe that it's not possible when it's needed to use data beyond 12M for calculations. I still hope there is some way!

Comment: I wanted to add that empty string will set the resolution to "Same as chart".